# Nested ifs to test if one or both of two conditions is true

Tags: javascript, optimization, if-statement, nested-if

I have an object, `data`, that may or may not contain the members `site_with_same_coords` and/or `site_with_same_name`. I test for these and if one or both exist, I alerts to the user:

```
if (data.site_with_same_coords){
    var SameCoordsExists = true;
    same_coords_message = 'The site ';
    same_coords_message += data.site_with_same_coords.name;
    same_coords_message += 'already already exists in the location you have indicated';
}

if (data.site_with_same_name){
    var SameNameExists = true;
    same_name_message = 'The site ';
    same_name_message += data.site_with_same_name.name;
    same_name_message += 'already already exists in a differnt location from the one you have indicated';
}

if (SameCoordsExists && SameNameExists){
    if(data.site_with_same_name.id != data.site_with_same_coords.id){
        alert(same_coords_message + '\n' + same_name_message);
    }else if (SameCoordsExists){
        alert(same_coords_message);
    }
    }else if (SameNameExists){
        alert(same_name_message);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could put them in an array and join them:

```
var messages = [];

if(data.site_with_same_coords) {
    messages.push('The site ' + data.site_with_same_coords.name + ' already exists in the location you have indicated');
}

if(data.site_with_same_name && !(data.site_with_same_coords && data.site_with_same_name.id === data.site_with_same_coords.id)) {
    messages.push('The site ' + data.site_with_same_name.name + ' already exists in a different location from the one you have indicated');
}

alert(messages.join('\n'));
```

Also, wouldn't the user be a bit confused if they received the message:

> The site some_site already exists in the location you have indicated
>     The site some_other_site already exists in a different location from the one you have indicated

? Just a thought.

Comment: This is helpful, but I only want to display both messages if another condition is true: `data.site_with_same_name.id != data.site_with_same_coords.id`. Can that be incorporated into this solution?

Comment: It looks like now it will only print just the `site_with_same_coords` message or both messages but never just the `site_with_same_name` message.

Comment: @Keyslinger: Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: LOL, `data` got changed to `date` in some places, but I think it's what I want now.

Answer (score 0):

This skeleton:

```
if (A && B) {
  if (C)
    print(msgA);
  print(msgB);
} else {
  print(msgA);
}
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
var AB = A && B;
if ((AB && C) || !AB)
  print(msgA);
if (AB)
  print(msgB);
```

as you can see, `msgA` and `msgB` appear only once, so you can create the strings on the fly right where they're printed. Obviously, in your case, `A` would be `data.site_with_same_coords`, `B` would be `data.site_with_same_name` and C would be `data.site_with_same_name.id != data.site_with_same_coords.id`.

It goes without saying that the rewritten version is much less readable.

update: if you really need to alert() then you'd do:

```
var AB = A && B;
if ((AB && C) || !AB)
  msg += msgA;
if (AB)
  msg += msgB;
if (msg)
  alert(msg);
```